# apex:inputField not correctly rendering

Tags: visualforce, css, slds, inputfield, apexinputfield

I use some apex:inputField components in my visualforce page but suggestion menu does not render correctly:

[image]

This is my code:

```
<apex:page standardController="Campaign" extensions="InvitationController" lightningStyleSheets="true">
    <style type="text/css">...</style>
    <apex:slds />
    <div class="slds-scope">
        <apex:pageBlock >
            <apex:pageMessages />
            <apex:form>
                <apex:pageBlockSection title="Filtres" columns="2">
                    <apex:inputField value="{!filtres.Contact__c}" styleClass="slds-input_height inputFilter inputFilter" />
                    ...
                </apex:pageBlockSection>
                ...
            </apex:form>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </div>
</apex:page>
```

This is the generated tag for the inputField suggestion menu:

```
<div id="j_id0:j_id4:j_id31:j_id32:j_id33_autoCompleteBoxId" class="autoCompleteBoxScrolling"
    style="width: 969px; top: 87px; height: auto; display: block; left: 175px;">
```

The computed width and left properties in the style attribute are wrong.

How to properly display an apex:inputField?

Comment: What did you define for `inputFilter` in your `<style type="text/css">` section?

Comment: @Basti if I remove the whole style tag, I still get the issue.